# Calling a method of an instance of a class

Tags: php

Forgive me for asking such a novice question, but I can't figure out how to call a method in PHP.  Here's what I'm trying to do (in pseudocode):

```
class Thing {
    public string Color() {
        return "taupe";
    }
}

Thing x = new Thing();
echo x.Color();
```

This should echo `taupe` as its result.  The part I'm getting stuck on is the last line: invoking the `Color` method of `x`.  How does one do this in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP, you would do something like:

```
class Thing {
   public function color() {
      return "taupe";
   }
}

$thing = new Thing;
echo $thing->color();
```

You were close :)

I suggest reading up on [PHP's OOP information here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). They've got a lot of good information about how to set up Objects and different patterns and whatnot.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$thing = new Thing();

echo $thing->Color();
```

Answer (score 1):

it's `$x-> Color();`. PHP uses -> instead of the dot (like in other languages) to call instance methods.
Also your code does not look like PHP.

`Thing x = new Thing();` should be something like `$x=new Thing();`

`public string Color() {` should look like `public function Color() {`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an illustration

```
$x = new Thing(); //Instantiate a class

echo $x -> Color(); //call the method
```